# Scheduled Reminders not being send

Tags: civimember, scheduled-reminders, civicrm-home

I want civi to send an email when our users renew their membership. I have setup the reminder as follows. but I have tested this couple of times by renewing my own membership offline but nothing gets sent.

What is it that im doing wrong [image]

I have set the time to 0 hours after activity date assuming that it will send the email as soon as the renewal.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check under Administer>System Settings>Scheduled Jobs and make sure the job is enabled. It should also show when it was last run.

If it is enabled you should make sure you have your cron job setup correctly. More info on that is here: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/scheduled-jobs/#initiation

Hope this helps!

Comment: also confirm you meet all criteria - ie Membership and member of Test Group

Comment: Thanks i got it to work. job was set to run daily. I managed to test it by clicking execute job now. Thanks for all your help